# Tampermonkey - Match default start page

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I try to remove the 8 tiles with the last seen pages on the start page of Chrome.
You know, the page which appears if you start Chrome.

But since there is no URL at all, I don't know what I have to enter at @match.
I've tried `// @match        *` but the script is not executed.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        *
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    setInterval(function(){
        var box = document.getElementById("mv-tiles");
        box.remove();
    },10
    );
})();
```

Comment: Setting `// @match *://*/_/chrome/newtab*` seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

Use `@include` instead of `@match`.

Also, it's possible to get the URL by going to the console and running `window.location.href`

I tried this and it worked:

```
// @include      http*://*chrome/newtab*
```

Maybe don't use an interval there, since it'll keep throwing errors once the element is not there anymore.

I'd use something like this:

```
injectStyles('#mv-single {display: none;}');

function injectStyles (styles) {
    var style       = document.createElement('style');
    style.type      = 'text/css';
    style.innerHTML = styles;
    document.head.appendChild(style);
}
```

Comment: Yes you are correct, it also works without the interval.

Comment: I have to unaccept this answer as solution since it does not work anymore.